# How to run Ssd1351 on Android Things?

Tags: i2c, android-things, ioerror

I use android things to run the Ssd1351 on RPI 3B.
My code:

```java
mI2cDevice = PeripheralManager.getInstance().openI2cDevice(i2cName, 0x3c);
mI2cDevice.writeRegByte(0, (byte)0xA5);
```

And the error:

> com.google.android.things.pio.PioException: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: I/O error

Comment: You should check your hardware connections. It looks like you're unable to communicate with the device at a wiring level.